# Angular 11 Cordova webview application not displaying FCM push message when the message is triggered from inside the application

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordovawebview

I have created an angular 11 Web application and hosted with firebase hosting. The same application converted to Android mobile app using cordova webview.

FCM is integrated in cordova webview using [cordova-plugin-firebase-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib#for-android-app)

Inside angular app its integrated using [AngularFireMessaging](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/messaging/messaging.md)

If I send message from Firebase console, its diplaying correctly in all the views. ie Notification is displayed in my installed cordova android application and also in browser.

I m sending notification to fcm from my angular app using

```
fcmUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
sendMessage(msgObject:{title: string, message: string}, isApp = true) {
let authorization = SERVER_KEY;
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('cache-control', 'no-cache')
  .set('content-type', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', authorization);

const body = {
  notification: {
    title: `${msgObject.title}`,
    body: `${msgObject.message}`
  },
  to : `${sessionStorage.getItem('messageToken')}`
};

return this.http
  .post(this.fcmUrl, body, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(res => res);
```

}

I have 2 apps created in firebase
WebApp and Android app. I have tried providing both the apps details for the configuration. But notification not displayed in my Android app (Cordova Webview) when triggered from my Angular service but displaying correctly If I send it from FCM cloud message console